# Why does vasodilation increase blood flow in the capillaries, but decrease it in the chest during inspiration?

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation

From *Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology*:

> Every time a person inspires, the pressure in the thoracic cavity becomes more negative than usual, causing the blood vessels in the chest to expand. This **reduces the quantity of blood returning to the left side of the heart** and thereby momentarily decreases the cardiac output and arterial pressure.

Why does vasodilation increase blood flow in the capillaries, but decrease it here?

As I understand it, vasodilation results in decreased resistance. According to Ohm's law, decreased resistance should increase blood flow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The passage isn't talking about a magical diameter increase in a physics problem. If negative outside pressure causes blood vessels to increase in diameter, something has to fill the vacated space inside: blood.

That means that some of the blood that would be flowing *through* the vessels into the heart is instead *filling the extra space* in the vessels themselves.

You could most directly model this in terms of analogy to electricity by thinking about the vessel walls as a capacitor, and it takes some time to charge that capacitor when the outside pressure is released. If you measure flow at the input, you'll see a higher flow because a good portion is charging the capacitor/filling the vessels, but if you measure flow at the output you'll find a reduction.

I'm not strongly familiar with the effect described in *Guyton and Hall* but I'm guessing that the "momentarily" word in there is doing a lot of work, as this effect is going to be brief relative to the respiratory cycle.

Comment: *...if you measure flow at the output you'll find a reduction.* This doesn't seem to happen in the capillaries (any capillaries, not necessarily in the chest) during vasodilation. Why?

Comment: @athlonusm It would *momentarily* if arterioles suddenly expanded. Once they are expanded and "full", though, there's nowhere to go but through. I don't know that it's possible for arterioles to expand via vasodilation as rapidly as you get in the chest from inspiration, though.